# How to calculate basic log expansion

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Without a calculator, so I cannot use the simple expansion of log(1+x)
Using wolfram we can see that

$\log(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2t}[\exp(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}})-1)])$

$=\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{t^{2}}{6n}+...$

But by hand,

$\exp(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}})=1+\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{4t^{2}}{2!n}+...$

$\exp(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}})-1=\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{4t^{2}}{2!n}+...$

and so plugging in and using the log taylor directly doesnt give the simplified result. so how can it be seen?

Comment: You need to keep one more term in the expansion of the exponential because of the cancellation of the $1$ and the loss of the $1$ in the expansion of $\log (1+x)$.  You also need to know or derive that $\log (1+x)\approx x-\frac {x^2}2$, but you should be able to do that by hand if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\exp\left( \frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\approx1+\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{4t^2}{2n}+\frac{8t^3}{6n\sqrt{n}}$$

\begin{align}\log(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2t}[\exp(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}})-1)]) &\approx \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2t}\left(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{n}} +\frac{4t^2}{2n}+\frac{8t^3}{6n\sqrt{n}}\right) \right)\\&=
\log \left(1 +\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{2t^2}{3n} \right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{2t^2}{3n}\right)^n}{n}\\
&\approx\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{2t^2}{3n} -\frac12\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}
 \right)^2\\
&= \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{t^2}{6n}
\end{align}